# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed

Tags: macos, ssh

In university I normally SSH into the computer sciences server. However today I keep getting the following error: `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`. SSHing with `-v` flags gives me the following.

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ... [...] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "~/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I've tried editing the hosts files but that won't help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen when you have too many different keys to offer. You can easily fix this by adding `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_keyname` to your `~/.ssh/config` entry used for this connection and a global `IdentitiesOnly yes`. This can look like this:

`~/.ssh/config`

```
Host foo
    hostname server.example.com
    User myUserName
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_keyname

Host *
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this same exact issue. My system log reflected:

```
/var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable
```

Going to `Disk Utility > Macintosh HD > Repair Disk Permissions` reset the permissions of `/var/empty` and solved the problem for me.

Comment: I ran into this issue when upgrading from El Capitan to Sierra. After changing the owner of /var/empty to root (`sudo chown root /var/empty/`), ssh works like a charm again. Thx!

Answer (score 8):

Little snitch was the problem for me.
`Rules > Incoming connections`

You must do this from the Little Snitch application's preferences.

[image: little snitch allow incoming ssh]

Comment: This description is not helpful. Where in MacOS (what edition of MacOS?) do I go to Rules > Incoming connections ?

Comment: As a matter of fact it is VERY helpful. It clearly says that "Little Snitch [may be the problem]".

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue, and resolved it by going to System Preferences on the Mac, open Sharing, and enable Remote Login.

In my case, I'd been able to access a reverse tunnel for years, but it stopped working after system settings were wiped in a hardware upgrade. This fixed it. Adding the IdentityFile did not.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur due to multiple reasons, in my case it was after upgrading to High Sierra (macOS).

```
Host *
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Test:

```
ssh -vvv  git@github.com
```

Further reading: https://github.com/jirsbek/SSH-keys-in-macOS-Sierra-keychain