# MacOS sshd Key Authentication: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: terminal, network, ssh

### Problem

I have a macOS running OpenBSD sshd. My goal is to disable password authentication and have only key authentication enabled.

1. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, when I set `PasswordAuthentication yes`, I can successfully connect to this machine using key authentication, and it did not ask me for the password.
   (Log: https://pastebin.com/raw/kJhGMT9v)
2. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, when I set `PasswordAuthentication no`, it shows the error message `kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`
   (Log: https://pastebin.com/raw/9i6Fj1P8)

My full `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`: https://pastebin.com/raw/T2uqtFGf

### What I have tried

- https://superuser.com/questions/804307/ssh-error-connection-closed-by-remote-host
  My system log shows only one relevant line: `Oct 20 16:57:01 HyDEV com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.08F6ACAC-B8ED-4FAD-91C1-70FA6CE831EC[69938]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255`
- [ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72607/ssh-exchange-identification-connection-closed/177540)
  Specifying a key on the client side did not solve my problem.

### Versions:

```
MacOS 11.6 (20G165)
OpenSSH 8.1p1
```

Comment: You may try to work around: Leave 'PasswordAuthentication yes' and set at the end 'Match User * PasswordAuthentication no'.

Comment: Could you try running it again with `-vvv` instead of just `-v`?